# CSS: How to make the inside border have fixed distance relative to resizable parent's border?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsf, primefaces

I'm developing a webpage were the front page displays a menu inside a resizable form (all using PrimeFace).

```
<p:layoutUnit position="west" size="315" minSize="180" maxSize="315" resizable="true" >
    <ui:include src="/menu.xhtml"  />
</p:layoutUnit>
```

From its layout, the parent form displays a border ("outside border") very similar to the menu's own border ("inside border").

[image: Borders]

I'ld like to make the inside border have a fixed distance relative to the outside one, in particular the right side of it, similar to the image above. Normally the menu's border doesn't stretch till his parent's border:

[image: normal border]

Naturally I could easily do that if the outside border had a fixed size: setting the menu's border with a fixed width. The problem is the outside border is resizable in the right side and so I need that the inside border be resizable as well always keeping the same distance to the outside border.

I tried doing that setting the width with a percent value, but it didn' work: the distance is either compressed or expanded when the outside border is resized. Based on other SO questions, I also tried inputting a fixed marging into it:

```
<p:menu toggleable="true" style="margin-right: 1px;" >
```

but the command was ignored. `box-sizing: border-box;` also didn't work, `right: 1px;` was useless as well and so using `resize`. So how could I do this?

Here is the first part of the menu's code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <body>
        <ui:composition>
            <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
                SO: irrelevant code here
                //]]> 
            </script> 

            <h:form id="id_menu" >
                <p:menu toggleable="true" >
                    <p:submenu label="Monitoramento" expanded="false" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the width of the menu div to auto like this:

```
<h:body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-menu.menu-west {
            width: auto;
        }
    </style>

    <p:layout>
        <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="315" minSize="180" maxSize="315" resizable="true">
            <h:form id="id_menu">
                <p:menu toggleable="true" styleClass="menu-west">
                    <p:submenu label="Monitoramento" expanded="false">
                        <p:menuitem value="Extrem long"/>
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:menu>
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            Content
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</h:body>
```

If you have the need, that the padding between the borders is equals on all four edges you can set:

```
.ui-layout-unit .ui-layout-unit-content {
    padding: 5px;
}
```